# Adding values of selected elements within an array in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, sum

I'm creating a trivia game. I have the following sample array of questions/answers/scores and not sure how to only sum up the scores of the answers that were guessed correctly, e.g. on question 1, if the person guesses "no" they get 27 points, then if they guess "sit" they get a total of 50 points (27 + 23) points and so on. I would like to input the total in a text area with id "#family1-score".

```
var currentQuestion = null;

var qData = [
    {question: 'Name a word that most people yell at their dogs', answers: ['no', 'sit', 'stay', 'down', 'fetch', 'jump'], scores: [27,23,14,7,6,5]},

    {question: 'Name a fruit you can eat with one bite.',
      answers: ['strawberry', 'grape', 'blueberry', 'raspberry', 'cherry', 'blackberry'],
      scores: [56,17,9,3,2,1]
    },

    {question: 'Name a holiday when people have parties.',
      answers: ['christmas', 'thanksgiving', 'halloween', '4th of july', 'labor day', 'new years eve'],
      scores: [35,21,11,3,2,1]
    }
];

$(".answerInputButton").click(function(){

    var answerData = $(".answerInput").val()
    //check if answer inputted is in the array of correct answers
    var isInArray = ($.inArray(answerData, qData[currentQuestion].answers) !== -1)
    //get the index of the correct answer from the array
    var indexOfAnswer = qData[currentQuestion].answers.indexOf(answerData)
    //get the score of the answer based on location of index of answer
    var answerScore = qData[currentQuestion].scores[indexOfAnswer]
    //the text of the answer tile when the answer is right
    var corrAnswer = answerData + " " + answerScore

    // console log the answer from the input field
    console.log(currPlayer + " your answer is ", answerData)

    if(isInArray) {
        if (currPlayer === player1Name) {
            answerCount++
            $("#family1-score").text(answerScore)


            console.log(currPlayer + ". You got " + answerCount + " answers right")
            //check if winner
            if (answerCount === 6) {
                gameMsg(currPlayer + " has won this round! " + currPlayer + ", get ready to start the next round")
                //reset board to next question
                //tally points in scorebox
                $("#answerArea").hide()
                $("#question").hide()
            }
        } 
        else if (currPlayer === player2Name) {
            answerCount++
            $("#family2-score").text(answerScore)           
            console.log(currPlayer + ". You got " + answerCount + " answers right")
            //check if winner
            if (answerCount === 6) {
                gameMsg(currPlayer + " has won this round! " + currPlayer + ", get ready to start the next round")
                //reset board to next question

                //tally points in scorebox
                $("#answerArea").hide()
                $("#question").hide()
            }
        }
        //console.log the score that corresponds to the index of the answer
        console.log("you received ", answerScore," points")
        // show green checkmark
        $("#greencheckmark").show().delay(2000).fadeOut()
        //flip corresponding answer tile with the answer and score
        if (indexOfAnswer === 0) {
            $("#frontAnswer1").removeClass("answerTile").addClass("rightAnswer").html(corrAnswer);
        } else if (indexOfAnswer === 1) {
            $("#frontAnswer2").removeClass("answerTile").addClass("rightAnswer").html(corrAnswer);
        } else if (indexOfAnswer === 2) {
            $("#frontAnswer3").removeClass("answerTile").addClass("rightAnswer").html(corrAnswer);
        } else if (indexOfAnswer === 3) {
            $("#frontAnswer4").removeClass("answerTile").addClass("rightAnswer").html(corrAnswer);
        } else if (indexOfAnswer === 4) {
            $("#frontAnswer5").removeClass("answerTile").addClass("rightAnswer").html(corrAnswer);
        } else if (indexOfAnswer === 5) 
            $("#frontAnswer6").removeClass("answerTile").addClass("rightAnswer").html(corrAnswer);
        } else {
            if (currPlayer === player1Name) {
                strikeCount ++
                console.log ('Try again')
                    if (strikeCount === 1) {
                        $("#onestrike").show().delay(2000).fadeOut()
                    } else if (strikeCount === 2) {
                        $("#twostrike").show().delay(2000).fadeOut()
                    } else if (strikeCount === 3) {
                        $("#threestrike").show().delay(2000).fadeOut()
                        //switch turns after a player gets 3 strikes
                        currPlayer = player2Name
                        //reset strike count to 0 for player 2
                        console.log(currPlayer + "'s turn now.")
                        //show message to next player that they can steal points for guessing any answer correctly in 5 seconds
                        gameMsg(currPlayer + ", you have 5 seconds to guess any remaining answer correctly and steal all the points. Get ready!")
                }
        }
        else if (currPlayer === player2Name) {
            strikeCount ++
            console.log ('Try again')
                if (strikeCount === 1) {
                    $("#onestrike").show().delay(2000).fadeOut()
                } else if (strikeCount === 2) {
                    $("#twostrike").show().delay(2000).fadeOut()
                } else if (strikeCount === 3) {
                    $("#threestrike").show().delay(2000).fadeOut()
                    //switch turns after a player gets 3 strikes
                    currPlayer = player1Name
                    //reset strike count to 0 for player 1
                    console.log(currPlayer + "'s turn now.")
                    //show message to next player that they can steal points for guessing any answer correctly in 5 seconds
                    gameMsg(currPlayer + ", you have 5 seconds to guess any remaining answer correctly and steal all the points. Get ready!")
                }
        }
        console.log("number of strikes is ", strikeCount)
    }
})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This seems a little ambiguous without the HTML. Could you edit your post and add the HTML or link to an example test at jsfiddle.net or the like?

Comment: Looking over this code, since `currentQuestion` is defined as `null` and never updated that I can see, your object index would fail when you attempt to get `qData[currentQuestion].answers`.

Comment: Started a Fiddle for this: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/z05ms3eo/